# How can I get selected value in dropdown on vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

My vue component, you can see this below

```
<template>
    <div>
        ...
        <select class="form-control" v-model="selected" @change="myFunction()">
            <option selected disabled>Status</option>
            <option v-for="status in orderStatus" v-bind:value="status.id">{{ status.name }}</option>
        </select>
        ...
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return{
                selected: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            myFunction: function() {
                console.log(this.selected)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

On the gulp exist error

> Vue template syntax error:
>
> : inline selected attributes on 
>   will be ignored when using v-model. Declare initial values in the
>   component's data option instead.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can solve it easily by putting this

```
<option disabled value="">Status</option>
```

Instead of this

```
<option selected disabled>Status</option>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select

> v-model will ignore the initial value, checked or selected attributes
> found on any form elements. It will always treat the Vue instance data
> as the source of truth. You should declare the initial value on the
> JavaScript side, inside the data option of your component.